# Disconnecting from host with Python Fabric when using the API

Tags: python, fabric

The website says:

> Closing connections: Fabric’s
>   connection cache never closes
>   connections itself – it leaves this up
>   to whatever is using it. The fab tool
>   does this bookkeeping for you: it
>   iterates over all open connections and
>   closes them just before it exits
>   (regardless of whether the tasks
>   failed or not.)
>
> **Library users will need to ensure they
>   explicitly close all open connections
>   before their program exits, though we
>   plan to makes this easier in the
>   future.**

I have searched everywhere, but I can't find out how to disconnect or close the connections.  I am looping through my hosts and setting env.host_string.  It is working, but hangs when exiting.  Any help on how to close?  Just to reiterate, I am using the library, not a fabfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to have to iterate through all open connections, `fabric.network.disconnect_all()` is what you're looking for. The docstring reads

> """
> Disconnect from all currently connected servers.
> Used at the end of `fab`'s main loop, and also intended for use by **library users**.
>
> """

Comment: I tried this but it gave an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'fabric' has no attribute 'network'`

Comment: The `fabric` version I have on my machine is `2.6.0`

Answer (score 4):

The main.py for fabric has this:

```
from fabric.state import commands, connections

for key in connections.keys():
    if state.output.status:
        print "Disconnecting from %s..." %, denormalize(key), connections[key].close()
```

fabric.state.connections is a dict with the value being: paramiko.SSHClient

So off I go to close those.

Comment: It's worth noting here to save people from searching, the key is whatever your host string is.

Comment: by the way, this is only if you are using 0.9.4 or older, the right answer is the just a sweet wrapper around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can disconnect from a specific connection, by host name, using the following code snippet (with fabric 1.10.1):

```
def disconnect(host):
    host = host or fabric.api.env.host_string
    if host and host in fabric.state.connections:
        fabric.state.connections[host].get_transport().close()
```

Comment: How will it work if one is not using `host_string` from environment? because when I print connection it prints the actual host as `{'ec2-user@xxxx:22': <paramiko.client.SSHClient object at 0x1013d09e8>}`

Answer (score 0):

```
from fabric.network import disconnect_all
disconnect_all()
```